# How to use curl to retrieve data from a php file?

Tags: php, curl

i have a `test.php` file that will hold a facebook app (iframe based php).

I also have a `dev environement` where all my files go before they are commited to `live`.

What i want to do is create a `curl page` on the `live` server that will be seen by facebook and that `curl page` will pull the data from my `test.php` page that sits on the `dev`

i have been trying but i get `Authorization Required`:

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://dev.xxx.com/test.php');

echo $returned_content ;
```

any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that is specific error. If you need facebook authorization, you must look at Facebook API for authorization methods. If you are getting HTTP authorization error, you may use apropriate CURL options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need curl?

Live:

```
<?php readfile('http://your.dev.server.example.com/test.php');?>
```

Comment: unfortunately yes. curl is what i need to use. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function